# Is it possible to use Google OAuth2 for none google services?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to connect to a none google service (3rd party site) that requires OAuth2 integration in my application.
Since the 3rd party service is not google, can I use google OAuth2? Or will I have to use a non-Google OAuth2 variant?

Comment: we are 'all' not google, what do you mean? google oauth provider is not bounded only to some google-like services, you can use it for example to authorize users in your web app

Answer (score 0):

Google Oauth2 is pretty much a standard implementation of [Oauth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).   Basically you are sending Authentication requests to Googles authentication servers which respond within the expected guidelines of the Oauth2 framework giving you access.

Your other system may also implement a standard version of Oauth2.  However to connect to them you are going to have to send authentication requests to their authentication server Not Googles.

You cant authenticate on Google and then use the same tokens to access another system.  While the implementations may be standard the Tokens need to be generated by the specific servers and cant be exchanged between them.

**Analogy:** Consider I have a key to my house it works in the lock on my front door.  What you want to do would use the key for my house in your front door.  Its not going to work the locks while designed the same (they are both locks) they are not the same lock and a key for one wont work in another.

**Answer:** I seriously doubt that you can use "code" designed to send authentication requests to Googles Authentication (Google Oauth) to another system without at the very least changing the Authentication end point URLs.